# How to use logging middleware created in server.js file in a imported route file

Tags: node.js, express, nodejs-server

I have quite confusing issue in my plate,
I have a server.js which is my first app entry point:

```
const test = require('./routers/test')

const express= require("express")

const pino = require('pino');
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger');

const logger = pino({ level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info' });
const expressLogger = expressPino({ logger });
const app= express();
const port= process.env.port || 4000
app.use(expressLogger);



app.use(express.json());
app.use(test);
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    logger.info(`Listening to port ${port}`);
});
```

As you see I have a logger(pino) and I use it and it works fine. Now I need to add a routes file to this entry point server file and the problem is exactly here. How can I pass down or use the logger I created in server.js in test.js route file(looking for best practices)?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();

router.get('test', (req, res)=>{
  console.log("THIS CONSOLE.LOG NEEDS TO BE REPLACED WITH LOGGER.INFO");  
  res.send(udsData.getDummyUrlResponse())
});

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to extract the logger to a separate module, e.x. `logger/index.js` and then import it wherever you need.

**./logger/index.js**

```
const pino = require('pino');
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger');

const logger = pino({ level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info' });
const expressLogger = expressPino({ logger });

module.exports = { logger, expressLogger };
```

**server.js**

```
const { logger, expressLogger } = require('./logger');

app.use(expressLogger);
...
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    logger.info(`Listening to port ${port}`);
});
```

**test.js**

```
const { logger } = require('./logger');
```

Comment: How about this part: const expressLogger = expressPino({ logger });
app.use(expressLogger); if I separate it how can I add it to app.use? will it work without adding it?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot and just out of curiosity if logger works already then what is the point of adding this at all: app.use(expressLogger);. I found the above code in a tutorial and wondering what is the role of that line?

Comment: It extends `express` functionality with additional logging features, like `request.log.info()` which is not available without it. Check out the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-pino-logger